# Regex to Match word in brackets with mysql and keyword

Tags: mysql, regex, pdo, keyword, brackets

I'm having problems matching a word or a group of words in a MySql query.

For example. In the database I have some sentences like: *(Just an example...)*

1. `John was fast.`
2. `Sussy was [fast].`
3. `Peter tied Jim for first place.`
4. `Jim tied Peter for [first] place.`

   ```
   $_query = $_link->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tblPeople WHERE `Text` REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',:keyword,'[[:>:]]') LIMIT :start,:count");
   ```

So the user enters a search term like this:

```
"was fast" OR "for first"
```

And the results would be **#1** for the first search or **#3** for the second search.

However I want the query to match the words inside the brackets, so searching for `was fast` would match **#1** and 2, and searching for `for first` would match **#3** and **#4**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you could remove those brackets from the table.

Comment: the brackets are important to the design. It is essential I keep the brackets or use formatted text instead.

Comment: You could perhaps use `REPLACE()` on Text to remove the `[]` from the `WHERE` clause, which shouldn't alter the table or output.

Comment: Already tried that. It removes the brackets from the output but I still get the same results when searching the database.

Comment: The only way I can think of this working is to copy the column to a new column in the database. One column would contain the brackets and one with out them. But that doesn't seem like it would be the best approach.